# Does" jinxed" here imply that her plans were ruined altogether or that everything fell apart during the holiday?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Does" jinxed" here imply that her plans were ruined altogether or that everything fell apart during the holiday?

> The strike has jinxed my plans to go to Hawaii for the holidays.

Comment: They didn't go to Hawaii due to the strike...

Answer (score 1):

"[jinx](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jinx)" merely means

> to cause a person or group to experience bad luck:

I think it means that the plans fell through, because it would be more usual to say that not the plans, but the trip, was jinxed, if things went unrelentingly bad on the trip, but the second meaning would be plausible if context made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a "malapropism", that is the word seems to me to be being used incorrectly.  "Jinx" has dictionary meanings of "cast a witch's spell", "bring bad luck" or in the sense of "A: It hasn't rained at all during the holiday.  B: Shhh, don't jinx it!"  It means "cause something to happen by mentioning it.

But in context it seems that a strike wouldn't "bring bad luck" and the other senses don't apply at all.  Instead the natural consequence of a strike would be for a flight to Hawaiʻi be cancelled.  That may be considered a misfortune, leading to the association with "jinx".  Nevertheless the strike doesn't bring bad luck to the flight or the trip.

So "jinx" was probably the wrong word to use here. Or, this may be a semantic shift in the word, in which it develops from meaning "bring bad luck", to "force someone to cancel".  I can find a couple of other examples of jinx being used in this way.  "I have jinxed my plans for the week - was supposed to be having friends to stay for a couple of nights as from today, so washed bedding, cleaned the guest bathroom & even cooked tonight's dinner last night. Then FancyMan tested positive this morning & he was round here yesterday, so plans have been cancelled. "[source](https://www.mumsnet.com/talk/other_subjects/4362960-Swagger-Inn-170-Autumn-is-here-with-a-vengeance-I-think-well-just-hide-under-the-duvet-with-HBFs-until-Spring?flipped=1)